# Print out all events and event handlers for all children concurrently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I got a task to intercept when user clicks on navigation. There is navigation control that is 'enhanced' with jquery mobile. Whole thing is a mess (there is more than one event fired when navigation is clicked) and I am trying to find which element is triggering what. I am thinking of writing function that accepts jquery selector and recursively traverses all children and prints out all events and event handlers (`console.log($(elem).data('events');`).
Does any of you have this script already by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it myself.

```
var printOutEvents = function (selector) {
    var parent = $(selector);

    function printer(item) {
        if (item.data('events') != undefined) {
            console.log(item);
            console.log(item.data('events'));
        }
        if (item.children().length > 0) {
            $.each(item.children(),
                function (i, it) {
                    printer($(it));
                });
        }
    };
    printer(parent);
}
```